# How can I extract XML value @attribute with suitescript in netsuite?

Tags: javascript, xml, netsuite

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="isokur.xsl"?>
<Tarih_Date Tarih="02.07.2015" Date="07/02/2015" Bulten_No="2015/127">
<Currency CrossOrder="0" Kod="USD" CurrencyCode="USD"><Unit>1</Unit><Isim>ABD DOLARI</Isim><CurrencyName>US DOLLAR</CurrencyName></Currency>
```

Hi 
How can I extract CurrencyCode="USD" attribute from this xml with suitescript ?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such XML parser in Restlet to get you your desired result. However if you're not bound to use Restlet then I would recommend you to use SuiteTalk. Using SuiteTalk you will have the luxury to use any XML parser. You can easily parse your XML file and obtain your result.

But if you don't have the luxury to use SuiteTalk, then one solution could be to convert your XML string in to JSON and get the value.

Here is the code to convert XML in to JSON:

```
xml2json={
    parser:function(xmlcode,ignoretags,debug){
        if(!ignoretags){ignoretags=""};
        xmlcode=xmlcode.replace(/\s*\/>/g,'/>');
        xmlcode=xmlcode.replace(/<\?[^>]*>/g,"").replace(/<\![^>]*>/g,"");
        if (!ignoretags.sort){ignoretags=ignoretags.split(",")};
        var x=this.no_fast_endings(xmlcode);
        x=this.attris_to_tags(x);
        x=escape(x);
        x=x.split("%3C").join("<").split("%3E").join(">").split("%3D").join("=").split("%22").join("\"");
        for (var i=0;i<ignoretags.length;i++){
            x=x.replace(new RegExp("<"+ignoretags[i]+">","g"),"*$**"+ignoretags[i]+"**$*");
            x=x.replace(new RegExp("</"+ignoretags[i]+">","g"),"*$***"+ignoretags[i]+"**$*")
        };
        x='<JSONTAGWRAPPER>'+x+'</JSONTAGWRAPPER>';
        this.xmlobject={};
        var y=this.xml_to_object(x).jsontagwrapper;
        if(debug){y=this.show_json_structure(y,debug)};
        return y
    },
    xml_to_object:function(xmlcode){
        var x=xmlcode.replace(/<\//g,"§");
        x=x.split("<");
        var y=[];
        var level=0;
        var opentags=[];
        for (var i=1;i<x.length;i++){
            var tagname=x[i].split(">")[0];
            opentags.push(tagname);
            level++
            y.push(level+"<"+x[i].split("§")[0]);
            while(x[i].indexOf("§"+opentags[opentags.length-1]+">")>=0){level--;opentags.pop()}
        };
        var oldniva=-1;
        var objname="this.xmlobject";
        for (var i=0;i<y.length;i++){
            var preeval="";
            var niva=y[i].split("<")[0];
            var tagnamn=y[i].split("<")[1].split(">")[0];
            tagnamn=tagnamn.toLowerCase();
            var rest=y[i].split(">")[1];
            if(niva<=oldniva){
                var tabort=oldniva-niva+1;
                for (var j=0;j<tabort;j++){objname=objname.substring(0,objname.lastIndexOf("."))}
            };
            objname+="."+tagnamn;
            var pobject=objname.substring(0,objname.lastIndexOf("."));
            if (eval("typeof "+pobject) != "object"){preeval+=pobject+"={value:"+pobject+"};\n"};
            var objlast=objname.substring(objname.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
            var already=false;
            for (k in eval(pobject)){if(k==objlast){already=true}};
            var onlywhites=true;
            for(var s=0;s<rest.length;s+=3){
                if(rest.charAt(s)!="%"){onlywhites=false}
            };
            if (rest!="" && !onlywhites){
                if(rest/1!=rest){
                    rest="'"+rest.replace(/\'/g,"\\'")+"'";
                    rest=rest.replace(/\*\$\*\*\*/g,"</");
                    rest=rest.replace(/\*\$\*\*/g,"<");
                    rest=rest.replace(/\*\*\$\*/g,">")
                }
            } 
            else {rest="{}"};
            if(rest.charAt(0)=="'"){rest='unescape('+rest+')'};
            if (already && !eval(objname+".sort")){preeval+=objname+"=["+objname+"];\n"};
            var before="=";after="";
            if (already){before=".push(";after=")"};
            var toeval=preeval+objname+before+rest+after;
            eval(toeval);
            if(eval(objname+".sort")){objname+="["+eval(objname+".length-1")+"]"};
            oldniva=niva
        };
        return this.xmlobject
    },
    show_json_structure:function(obj,debug,l){
        var x='';
        if (obj.sort){x+="[\n"} else {x+="{\n"};
        for (var i in obj){
            if (!obj.sort){x+=i+":"};
            if (typeof obj[i] == "object"){
                x+=this.show_json_structure(obj[i],false,1)
            }
            else {
                if(typeof obj[i]=="function"){
                    var v=obj[i]+"";
                    //v=v.replace(/\t/g,"");
                    x+=v
                }
                else if(typeof obj[i]!="string"){x+=obj[i]+",\n"}
                else {x+="'"+obj[i].replace(/\'/g,"\\'").replace(/\n/g,"\\n").replace(/\t/g,"\\t").replace(/\r/g,"\\r")+"',\n"}
            }
        };
        if (obj.sort){x+="],\n"} else {x+="},\n"};
        if (!l){
            x=x.substring(0,x.lastIndexOf(","));
            x=x.replace(new RegExp(",\n}","g"),"\n}");
            x=x.replace(new RegExp(",\n]","g"),"\n]");
            var y=x.split("\n");x="";
            var lvl=0;
            for (var i=0;i<y.length;i++){
                if(y[i].indexOf("}")>=0 || y[i].indexOf("]")>=0){lvl--};
                tabs="";for(var j=0;j<lvl;j++){tabs+="\t"};
                x+=tabs+y[i]+"\n";
                if(y[i].indexOf("{")>=0 || y[i].indexOf("[")>=0){lvl++}
            };
            if(debug=="html"){
                x=x.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
                x=x.replace(/\n/g,"<BR>").replace(/\t/g,"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
            };
            if (debug=="compact"){x=x.replace(/\n/g,"").replace(/\t/g,"")}
        };
        return x
    },
    no_fast_endings:function(x){
        x=x.split("/>");
        for (var i=1;i<x.length;i++){
            var t=x[i-1].substring(x[i-1].lastIndexOf("<")+1).split(" ")[0];
            x[i]="></"+t+">"+x[i]
        }   ;
        x=x.join("");
        return x
    },
    attris_to_tags: function(x){
        var d=' ="\''.split("");
        x=x.split(">");
        for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            var temp=x[i].split("<");
            for (var r=0;r<4;r++){temp[0]=temp[0].replace(new RegExp(d[r],"g"),"_jsonconvtemp"+r+"_")};
            if(temp[1]){
                temp[1]=temp[1].replace(/'/g,'"');
                temp[1]=temp[1].split('"');
                for (var j=1;j<temp[1].length;j+=2){
                    for (var r=0;r<4;r++){temp[1][j]=temp[1][j].replace(new RegExp(d[r],"g"),"_jsonconvtemp"+r+"_")}
                };
                temp[1]=temp[1].join('"')
            };
            x[i]=temp.join("<")
        };
        x=x.join(">");
        x=x.replace(/ ([^=]*)=([^ |>]*)/g,"><$1>$2</$1");
        x=x.replace(/>"/g,">").replace(/"</g,"<");
        for (var r=0;r<4;r++){x=x.replace(new RegExp("_jsonconvtemp"+r+"_","g"),d[r])}  ;
        return x
    }
};


if(!Array.prototype.push){
    Array.prototype.push=function(x){
        this[this.length]=x;
        return true
    }
};

if (!Array.prototype.pop){
    Array.prototype.pop=function(){
        var response = this[this.length-1];
        this.length--;
        return response
    }
};
```

Parse your xml string as below :

```
var myJsonObject=xml2json.parser('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="isokur.xsl"?><Tarih_Date Tarih="02.07.2015" Date="07/02/2015" Bulten_No="2015/127"><Currency CrossOrder="0" Kod="USD" CurrencyCode="USD"><Unit>1</Unit> <Isim>ABD DOLARI</Isim> <CurrencyName>US DOLLAR</CurrencyName>  </Currency></Tarih_Date>');
```

It will return you something like this :

[image]

Then simply you can get the value by

```
var currency_code = myJsonObject.tarih_date.currency.currencycode;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the xml value as a string then you can make calls like the following:

```
var xml = '<Currency CrossOrder="0" Kod="USD" CurrencyCode="USD"><Unit>1</Unit><Isim>ABD DOLARI</Isim><CurrencyName>US DOLLAR</CurrencyName></Currency>';
var asDoc = nlapiStringToXML(xml);
nlapiSelectValue(asDoc, 'Currency/@CurrencyCode');
```

Use the NS help to get full docs on all the nlapiSelectxxx calls. The above works client side. It should work server side as well.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. NS XPath docs clearly specify that to get the attribute just use _parent/@attribute_.